Rudin’s RCA Theorem $7.26$ part $1$.
These are definitions which we use in the proof of the theorem:

This is lemma $7.25$ which is used in the proof:

There is the theorem:
Suppose that
$(i)$ $X \subset V \subset R^{k}$, $V$ is open, $T : V \to R^{k}$ is continuous;
$(ii)$ $X$ is Lebesgue measurable, $T$ is one-to-one on $X$, and $T$ is differentiable at every point of $X$;
$(iii)$ $ m(T(V - X)) = 0.$
Then, setting $Y = T(X)$, $$ \int_{Y} f dm = \int_{X} (f \circ T) |J_{T}| dm$$
for every measurable $f : R^{k} \to [0,\infty]$.
The $\sigma$-algebra consisting of the Lebesgue measurable subsets of $R^{k}$ will be denoted by $\mathfrak {M}$
The proof is broke into thee steps:
There is the first step:
$(1)$ If $E \in \mathfrak {M}$ and $E \subset V$, then $T(E) \in \mathfrak {M}$.
There is its' proof:
If $E_0 \in \mathfrak {M},E_0 \subset V $, and $m(E_0) = 0$, then $m(T(E_0 - X)) = 0$ by $(iii)$, and $m(T(E_0 \cap X)) = 0$ by lemma $7.25$. Thus $m(T(E_0)) = 0$.
I don't understand how do we get by lemma $7.25$ that $m(T(E_0 \cap X)) = 0$ and how do we conclude from there that $m(T(E_0)) = 0$.
Any help would be appreciated.

Hi! Could you elaborate a bit on what you don't understand here, so we can better help you? It can be as simple as telling us what stops you when trying to test the conditions of the lemma on $E = E_0 \cap X$.

@BrunoB I get it now that differentiability ensures that but how do we get from there that $m(T(E_0)) = 0$ ?

You have $E_0 = (E_0 \cap X) \cup (E_0 \setminus X)$. What happens when applying $T$?

@BrunoB Why can't we apply lemma $7.25$ directly on $E_0$?

Because $T$ is only assumed to be differentiable on $X$, nowhere else in $V$.

I'm writing down this answer both because I think you understood the gist of it and to make this question leave the Unanswered queue.
For $x \in E_0 \cap X \subset X$, $T$ is differentiable at $x$ by $(ii)$, thus the $\limsup$ from the lemma is actually a limit and is finite. And since $E_0 \cap X \subset E_0$ with $m(E_0) = 0$, we get that $m(E_0 \cap X) = 0$, thus we can apply the lemma to $E = E_0 \cap X$. For general $x \in E_0$ we did not know whether $T$ was differentiable at $x$ or not, which is why this proof is done case-by-case.
Now it only remains to see that $T(E_0) = T(E_0 \cap X) \cup T(E_0 \setminus X)$ to conclude that $$0 \leq m(T(E_0)) \leq m(T(E_0 \cap X)) + m(T(E_0 \setminus X)) = 0 + 0 = 0$$ hence $$m(T(E_0))=0$$
